# Getting month from MM-DD-YYYY format sql

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to get only the month from my date column and I can't seem to get it using my query.

The `DATE` is my column field and I only want to display the month. Can any of you help me on this?

Query:

```
SELECT MONTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(DATE), 1)) FROM adjtime WHERE EMPLOYEE = 302
```

Comment: Your code looks a lot like SQL Server, so I changed the tag.

Comment: Is the data type of the column `DATE` is `DATETIME` or else? Didn't understand why you are using `GETDATE(DATE)`, in this case `SELECT MONTH(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [DATE], 1))` will work.

Comment: My DATE column is like this 1/1/2017.... 
and I'm using MySql from phpmyadmin

Comment: @VirgilCruz I've changed the Sql-Server tag to MySql based on your last comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the `DATE` is in varchar, you need to convert as `DATE` format using

```
STR_TO_DATE(`DATE`, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

Sample execution with sample data:

```
CREATE TABLE `adjtime` (EMPLOYEE int, `DATE` VARCHAR (20) );

INSERT INTO `adjtime` (EMPLOYEE , `DATE`) 
SELECT 302, '1/1/2017' UNION
SELECT 302, '11/22/2017' UNION
SELECT 302, '2/20/2017' UNION
SELECT 301, '3/6/2017';

SELECT MONTH(STR_TO_DATE(`DATE`, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS `MonthNumber` 
FROM `adjtime` 
WHERE `EMPLOYEE` = 302;
```

or

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(STR_TO_DATE(`DATE`, '%m/%d/%Y')) AS `MonthName` 
FROM `adjtime` 
WHERE `EMPLOYEE` = 302;
```

Rextester Demo: http://rextester.com/GFOTO88036

Comment: @VirgilCruz Please let this be a lesson to you on how to ask a good question. Gordon guessed Sql Server. Young guessed Oracle. I guessed your column is of a date/datetime data type. Please don't make us guess. Include all the relevant details in the question to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a `DATE` column, then in SQL Server you can get the numeric month by doing:

```
select month(datecol)
```

or

```
select datepart(month, datecol)
```

If you want the name of the month, use `datename()`:

```
select datename(month, datecol)
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle? SQL Server? MySQL?

Oracle Syntax:

```
TO_CHAR('05/29/2017', 'MONTH')
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, MySql have `month` and `monthname` functions. You can read about them in the [official documentation.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month)

So if it's MySql, your query should probably look like this:

```
SELECT MONTH(`DATE`) 
FROM `adjtime` 
WHERE `EMPLOYEE` = 302
```

To get the month's name, use this:

```
SELECT MONTHNAME(`DATE`) 
FROM `adjtime` 
WHERE `EMPLOYEE` = 302
```

Comment: The query worked. But it returned null results.. My format for the date is 1/1/2017. Maybe its reading like 2017.1.1?

Comment: Date is not stored with display format. Anyway, I see that Arulkumar have already given you the correct answer.